# Why NASA hosts many of their reports public, while ESA/JAXA/ Roscomos doesn't?

Tags: rockets, nasa, technology, policy

There are abundant resources available online in [NTRS](https://www.sti.nasa.gov/) about the hard earned knowledge of rocket science. But NASA makes them available for free for all.

But there does exist some classified documents. So, on what basis does NASA decide to release its work to public?

Considering the argument that NASA functions on tax payer's money, and hence releasing to public is essential only raises another question - why make it available to the entire world?

There are other government organisations that simply doesn't release much information, compared to NASA. There must be a compelling reason for NASA to do so and to continue the policy.

Answer (score 5):

In the USA, there is principle that documents produced with tax-payers money are public domain.  That applies to NASA, but also, for example, to topographic maps produced by the USGS, or by anything else produced by a federal employee.

There is no such principle in Europe.  Organisations like ESA and EUMETSAT are quite restrictive in sharing of reports or raw data, motivated by a variety of reasons, but essentially because it's what their bureaucratic rules say.